# Sending Value from Switch Function to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, switch-statement, uilabel

Made a switch function with 12 different cases with two variables each. However, I can't any of the cases to work. I need the value of the listPriceTextField to go through the equation laid out in the switch function and then I need that value to be passed to my takebackLabel. Kept the code down to just the first scenario to keep it simple. Theres probably something in here that I wrote wrong, was trying to piece together info from various different YouTube videos around the same topic.

`import UIKit`

`class ViewControllerTakeback: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {`

```
var currentTextField = UITextField()
var pickerView = UIPickerView()
var levelTextField = UITextField()
var levelPickerView = UIPickerView()

var PlatformType:[String] = []
var Platform2Type:[String] = []
var PLevel:[String] = []
var PLevel2: [String] = []


//picker & text fields
@IBOutlet weak var platformTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var platformTextField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pLevelTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pLevel2TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var takebackLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var retailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var listPriceTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var listPriceTextField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var takebackLabel2: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

//data for platformTextField & platformTextField2 via pickerView
    `PlatformType = ["StockX","GOAT","Stadium Goods","Flight Club","Grailed","PayPal"]
    Platform2Type = ["StockX","GOAT","Stadium Goods","Flight Club","Grailed","PayPal"]`

//data for pLevelTextField & pLevel2TextField via pickerView
    `PLevel = ["1","2","3","4","Domestic","International","Invoice"]
    PLevel2 = ["1","2","3","4","Domestic","International","Invoice"]`

```
    //variables for takeback calculation
    let a = "StockX", b = "GOAT", c = "Stadium Goods", d = "Flight Club", e = "Grailed", f = "PayPal"
    let aa = "1", bb = "2", cc = "3", dd = "4", ee = "Domestic", ff = "International", gg = "Invoice"

    let TB1: Double = 0, TB2: Double = 0, TB3: Double = 0, TB4: Double = 0, TB5: Double = 0, TB6: Double = 0, TB7: Double = 0, TB8: Double = 0, TB9: Double = 0, TB10: Double = 0, TB11: Double = 0, TB12: Double = 0
    let TB2_1: Double = 0,TB2_2: Double = 0,TB2_3: Double = 0,TB2_4: Double = 0,TB2_5: Double = 0,TB2_6: Double = 0,TB2_7: Double = 0,TB2_8: Double = 0,TB2_9: Double = 0,TB2_10: Double = 0,TB2_11: Double = 0,TB2_12: Double = 0

retailTextField.delegate = self
    listPriceTextField.delegate = self
    listPriceTextField2.delegate = self
```

`guard let platformTextField = platformTextField.text else { return }
     guard let pLevelTextField = pLevelTextField.text else { return }
        guard let listPriceTextField = Double(listPriceTextField.text!) else {return}`

```
    switch (platformTextField,pLevelTextField) {

        case (a, aa):
        if TB1 == Double(listPriceTextField) * (1 - 0.125) {
               return takebackLabel.text = "\(TB1)" }
            else {return}

         case (a, bb):
                if TB2 == Double(listPriceTextField) * (1 - 0.12) {
                   self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB2)" }
                else {return}

         case (a, cc):
                if TB3 == Double(listPriceTextField) * (1 - 0.115) {
                   self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB3)" }
                else {return}

         case (a, dd):
                if TB4 == Double(listPriceTextField) * (1 - 0.11) {
                   self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB4)" }
                else {return}

         case (b, aa):
                if TB5 == Double((listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.095) - 5) * 1 - 0.029) {
                   takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB5)" }
                else {return}

         case (b, bb):
                if TB6 == Double((listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.15) - 5) * 1 - 0.029) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB6)" }
                else {return}

         case (b, cc):
                if TB7 == Double((listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.2) - 5) * 1 - 0.029) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB7)" }
                else {return}

         case (c, aa):
                if TB8 == Double(listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.2)) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB8)" }
                else {return}

         case (d, aa):
                if TB9 == Double(listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.2)) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB9)" }
                else {return}

        case (e, ee):
                if TB10 == Double((listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.089)) - 0.3) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB10)" }
                else {return}
        case (e, ff):
            if TB11 == Double((listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.104)) - 0.3) {
                self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB11)" }
            else {return}

         case (f, gg):
            if TB12 == Double(listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.029)) {
                self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB12)" }
            else {return}

         default:
            print("Enter Item Info")
         }
```

`guard let platformTextField2 = platformTextField2.text else { return }
    guard let pLevel2TextField = pLevel2TextField.text else { return }
        guard let listPriceTextField2 = Double(listPriceTextField2.text!) else {return}`

```
    switch (platformTextField2,pLevel2TextField) {

         case (a, aa):
                if TB2_1 == Double(listPriceTextField2) * (1 - 0.125) {
                   takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_1)" }
                else {return}

         case (a, bb):
                if TB2_2 == Double(listPriceTextField2) * (1 - 0.12) {
                  takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_2)" }
                else {return}

         case (a, cc):
                if TB2_3 == Double(listPriceTextField2) * (1 - 0.115) {
                  takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_3)" }
                else {return}

         case (a, dd):
                if TB2_4 == Double(listPriceTextField2) * (1 - 0.11) {
                  takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_4)" }
                else {return}

         case (b, aa):
                if TB2_5 == Double((listPriceTextField2 * (1 - 0.095) - 5) * 1 - 0.029) {
                   takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_5)" }
                else {return}

         case (b, bb):
                if TB2_6 == Double((listPriceTextField2 * (1 - 0.15) - 5) * 1 - 0.029) {
                    self.takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_6)" }
                else {return}

         case (b, cc):
                if TB2_7 == Double((listPriceTextField2 * (1 - 0.2) - 5) * 1 - 0.029) {
                    self.takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_7)" }
                else {return}

         case (c, aa):
                if TB2_8 == Double(listPriceTextField2 * (1 - 0.2)) {
                    self.takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_8)" }
                else {return}

         case (d, aa):
                if TB9 == Double(listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.2)) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB2_9)" }
                else {return}

        case (e, ee):
                if TB10 == Double((listPriceTextField * (1 - 0.089)) - 0.3) {
                    self.takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB2_10)" }
                else {return}
        case (e, ff):
            if TB2_11 == Double((listPriceTextField2 * (1 - 0.104)) - 0.3) {
                return takebackLabel2.text! = "\(TB2_11)" }
            else {return}

         case (f, gg):
            if TB2_12 == Double(listPriceTextField2 * (1 - 0.029)) {
                takebackLabel.text! = "\(TB2_12)" }
            else {return}

         default:
            print("Enter Item Info")
         }
        }
```

Comment: Is it hitting the switch statement at all (i.e. is it getting past the guard functions)? Also, might help if you post the full switch statement.

Comment: ok ill put it all up right now. Not sure how to tell if it passes the guard functions. All I know is that I cannot get anything outputted into the UILabelField.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the start of the switch statement and run the app to see if that line gets hit or not. If it's not hit, then it's getting caught by one of the guards. You can set breakpoints on each guard statement as well. If you don't know how to set a breakpoint in Xcode, just mouse-click in the gutter of the line you want to stop at (https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711).

Comment: will give that a try, thank you !